# Raise Error in Update Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I'm running a SP to update a balance in an account. Here is the SP code:

```
CREATE procedure UpdateBalance(@LedgerID as int,@TransDate as DateTime,@Neg as smallint) as
Begin
Declare @OpenBal as decimal(12,2)
Select Top 1 @OpenBal=Balance From Trans Inner Join TransGroup On Trans.TGID=TransGroup.TGID And TransDate<@TransDate Where LedgerID=@LedgerID Order By TransDate,TransGroup.TGID;
With CTE as
(Select TransGroup.TGID,LedgerID,Amount,Balance,Sum(Amount) Over(Order By TransDate,TransGroup.TGID) as 'Total' From Trans Inner Join TransGroup On Trans.TGID=TransGroup.TGID And TransDate>=@TransDate Where LedgerID=@LedgerID)
Update CTE Set Balance=Total+@OpenBal
End
```

The SP runs fine and updates the balances of the account from `@TransDate` onwards.

The `@Neg` parameter is currently unused and will have a value of either 0, -1 or 1.

If the `@Neg` parameter is non-zero, I want the SP to fail if the sign of `Total+@OpenBal` value being updated does not match the sign of the `@Neg` parameter.

For example, if `@Neg` is 1, then `Balance` should always be positive and the SP should fail if it becomes negative at any row.

Of course, a simple solution is to put the Update statement in a transaction, run a Select statement to check for negative balances and then commit or rollback the transaction accordingly. But I want to know if there is a way to raise an error within the `Update CTE Set Balance=Total+@OpenBal` statement so that it automatically rolls back everything.

I tried something like this - but learnt that `Throw` can't be called within a `Case` statement.

```
Update CTE Set Balance=Case @Neg When 0 Then Total+@OpenBal When 1 Then Case When Total+@OpenBal<0 Then Throw Else Total+@OpenBal End When -1 Then Case When Total+@OpenBal<0 Then Throw Else Total+@OpenBal End End
```

Any ideas?

Comment: another option is handling the balances by triggers on update

Comment: A trigger will just run once for an update statement, not for each row - even if you are updating a whole table... Secondly, the trigger will fire after all rows have been updated. Thirdly, a trigger cannot perform a rollback.

Comment: Ok. I managed it by replacing Throw with 'ABCD'. This will cause a varchar conversion error and the update statement will fail. I'm not very happy with this because I wanted a custom error. Anyway, it will have to do for now...

Answer (score 1):

You can't throw a custom exception within an UPDATE statement.

You have a few options:

1. Use an INSTEAD OF trigger on update. You can prevent the update from ever occurring if you want, throw a custom error, etc.
2. In the procedure, do your Total + @OpenBal computations and insert them into a table variable. SELECT for invalid values, if you find some you can throw a custom error; otherwise, join your table variable with whatever else you need and do the update

Throwing by inserting bad values is a hack and the error will be confusing to anyone using your stored procedure. It will look like your code has errors.

I am a little curious though - why would you want to store the sign separately and then verify another value has the same sign? Your design sounds denormalized.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I wanted to avoid triggers as far as possible. But it may be my only option left. Table variable is also another good option. The reason why I need to store the sign separately: in accounting, we can have accounts that can have a negative balance (such as a customer's receivables account) and we can also have accounts that can never have a negative balance (such as a cash-in-hand account). Hence, depending on the account type, it is necessary to check whether all resulting balances are correct.

Comment: Have you looked into CHECK constraints? You can use UDFs in CHECK constraints which lets you do quite a lot with them. For example, see here - http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/using-udf-check-constraint-validate-column